# String Builder not working in TextView Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, stringbuilder

Hey I want to give **space\tab** between two words in a string to display in TextView. I have **mutableListOf** of string and doing iteration for each string. In Iteration i searching first **space** and replacing with **\t** and storing in **string builder** it working fine what i want and checking in logs it's fine. But i set texting it not working in text view.

```
    val list = mutableListOf(
        "1. Log in Google account\n",
        "2. Scroll to the page\n",
        "3. Tap disconnect from account to logout"
    )
    val content = StringBuilder()
    list.forEach{ string->
        content.append(string.replaceFirst(" " , "\t"))
    }
    System.out.print("string >> $content")
    list_string.text = content
```

As you see it fine in logs

[image: In Logs]

But when i am setting text in text view it's not working

[image: Not Working]

Also i want to give **margin/padding** between lines i.e. **1st** point has some margin bottom/padding bottom to **2nd** point i don't use **\n**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use StringBuilder to complete your requirements. I use joinToString to solve this problem.

```kotlin
    private lateinit var tv: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4)
        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        val list = mutableListOf(
            "1. Log in Google account\n",
            "2. Scroll to the page\n",
            "3. Tap disconnect from account to logout"
        )
        list.forEach{ string->
            string.replaceFirst(" " , "\t")
        }

        tv.text = list.joinToString(separator = "")
    }
```

As for how to modify the spacing between the first line and the second line, you can set `android:lineHeight="40dp"` to solve

```xml
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:lineHeight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

[image]